# match two image positions with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to simulate something like iOS7 style, with frost blur background.

I have a image background on body and sidebar which should look like iOS7.

the problem is that I cannot match body and sidebar positions.
Also this sidebar will move up and down.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K9BCq/1/

problem is that I use `background-size: cover` on body and since sidebar is statically 200px wide, they will never match exactly

Comment: You want to split screen 50-50 on one side blur:0 and second blur: 10. That's correct?

Comment: no, I want a background 100% of this image and sidebar 200px wide. body blur:0 and sidebar 10

Comment: I think with css you wont accomplish that. On the other hand you can try to use http://www.blurjs.com/ which I think will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried using this and it worked for me.

```
background-size:cover;
bacground-position:84%;
```

This will work but you have to manage the background position according to your sidebar position.

http://jsfiddle.net/K9BCq/2/

Comment: I was trying to find css only solution.

Comment: I am sorry but this is a CSS solution, isn't it ?